# Count number of objects of class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have declared a Recipe class and create 16 objects manually.In my application one object is my one row.

so i need to return no of rows in method numberOfRowsInSection

How can I return the no of objects that Recipe class have

Here is my view controller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
    recipe1.name = @"Egg Benedict";
    recipe1.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe1.imageFile = @"egg_benedict.jpg";
    recipe1.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 fresh English muffins", @"4 eggs", @"4 rashers of back bacon", @"2 egg yolks", @"1 tbsp of lemon juice", @"125 g of butter", @"salt and pepper", nil];

    Recipe *recipe2 = [Recipe new];
    recipe2.name = @"Mushroom Risotto";
    recipe2.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe2.imageFile = @"mushroom_risotto.jpg";
    recipe2.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 tbsp dried porcini mushrooms", @"2 tbsp olive oil", @"1 onion, chopped", @"2 garlic cloves", @"350g/12oz arborio rice", @"1.2 litres/2 pints hot vegetable stock", @"salt and pepper", @"25g/1oz butter", nil];

    Recipe *recipe3 = [Recipe new];
    recipe3.name = @"Full Breakfast";
    recipe3.prepTime = @"20 min";
    recipe3.imageFile = @"full_breakfast.jpg";
    recipe3.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 sausages", @"100 grams of mushrooms", @"2 rashers of bacon", @"2 eggs", @"150 grams of baked beans", @"Vegetable oil", nil];
    .
    .
    .
   // up to 16 objects
    .
    .
    .
    Recipe *recipe15 = [Recipe new];
    recipe15.name = @"Angry Birds Cake";
    recipe15.prepTime = @"4 hours";
    recipe15.imageFile = @"angry_birds_cake.jpg";
    recipe15.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12 tablespoons (1 1/2 sticks) unsalted butter", @"2 1/2 cups all-purpose flour", @"1 tablespoon baking powder", @"1 teaspoon salt", @"1 3/4 cups sugar", @"2 large eggs, plus 3 large egg yolks", @"1 cup of milk", nil];

    Recipe *recipe16 = [Recipe new];
    recipe16.name = @"Ham and Cheese Panini";
    recipe16.prepTime = @"10 min";
    recipe16.imageFile = @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg";
    recipe16.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 tablespoons unsalted butter", @"4 cups thinly sliced shallots", @"2 teaspoons fresh thyme", @"1/4 cup grainy Dijon mustard", @"8 slices rustic white bread", @"8 slices Gruyere cheese", @"8 ounces sliced cooked ham", nil];

}
```

Here is my numberOfRowInSection method

How can I return the number of rows i.e. 16

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //how can I return no of rows (no of objects)

}
```

Comment: if you manually created 16 instances and need 16 rows... make it return 16

Comment: or.... add the 16 individuals to an array you keep around that would make it easier IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use an array, put all your recipes in an array and return the count of such array on the tableView datasource. Something like

```
// Declare it on your interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *recipes;
...

// On your viewDidLoad
self.recipes = @[recipe1, recipe2]; // and so on
...

// UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.recipes.count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to add a static variable to the class' implementation and also provide a method to get its value.

This variable will be increased by one when you call the constructor of the `Recipe` class and decrease by one when you call the destructor.

Comment: Didn't know that Objective-C has a constructor and destructor. And really, this is an awful design. He needs to know the number of objects that officially exist for his view controller.

Comment: The point is not how it is implemented, but that there is a constructor behaviour if you like. 

Traditionaly, object counting is implemented by static class members. Objective-C has static variables (actually, they are C like static but serves almost the same). Thus, the class should know by it self how many objects it has created. You should not keep track by counting pointers or anything else. In the alloc or dealloc method of each object, the counter/static variable of the class' implementation file should be treated.